# Conditional rewrite rule

Tags: antlr

Take the following pseudo-rule:

```
rule: prefix? rest;
```

I would like to rewrite the AST based on the appearance of prefix.

If there isn't a prefix, I would like it to be rewritten as `rest`.

If there is a prefix, I would like it to be rewritten as `(PARENT prefix rest)`

```
PARENT 
-prefix
-rest
```

In other words, I want to make a token appear in the AST if a 0 or 1 alternative is found.

[How] is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Divide it in two separate alternatives:

```
rule
 : prefix rest -> ^(PARENT prefix rest)
 | rest        -> rest
 ;
```